# Does calling method, and directly reading/setting private fields of the argument, breaks encapsulation?

Tags: c#, class, oop

consider the following code:

```
public class Counter
{
    private int _value;

    // public int Value => _value;
    // commented for asking purposes

    public void Increment() {
        _value++;
    }

    public void Decrement() {
        _value--;
    }

    public void CopyOtherCounter(Counter other)
    {
        _value = other._value;
        // the compiler didn't show any error here
        // why it does not break encapsulation?
    }
}
```

I would like to ask does this means breaking encapsulation or not.

Edit: because I think I shouldn't be able to read other object private value, even though it have the same type. Because this could happen:

```
public class Person {
    private float _walletMoney; // no getter
    private void StealFrom(Person other) {
        _walletMoney += other._walletMoney; //reading other private wallet
        other._walletMoney = 0; //writing other private wallet
    }
}

void Main() {
    var John = new Person();
    var Bob = new Person();
    John.StealFrom(Bob);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it is breaking encapsulation?

Comment: By creating public methods and properties you created public surface area. Other code can interact with `Counter` class using these public surface area. If your public methods/properties changing any private field that will not violate encapsulation principle.

Comment: Encapsulation is enclosing one or more items (data members & methods) within a physical or logical package which for c# is a class. check this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_encapsulation.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Encapsulation (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))

> In object-oriented programming (OOP), encapsulation refers to the
> bundling of data with the methods that operate on that data, or the
> restricting of direct access to some of an object's components

By definition it's still encapsulated, it's within the type, and it has a very specific accessibility domain!

To put it simply, **you can access private fields within the type that defined it**, this also included nested *types*/*classes* (even if you are dealing with a reference to the type), as such (and defined by the specifications) it's permitted.

To get the specific documentation on this, you really have to go for a deep-dive through the C# Specification [which you can find here](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)

Here are the important parts

> **8.5.2 Declared accessibility**
>
> ...
>
> - Private, which is selected by including a private modifier in the member declaration. The intuitive meaning of private is “**access
>   limited to the containing type**

Further more

> **8.5.3 Accessibility domains**
>
> ...
>
> The accessibility domain of a nested member M declared in a type T
> within a program P, is defined as follows (noting that M itself might
> possibly be a type):
>
> ...
>
> - If the declared accessibility of M is private, the accessibility domain of M is the program text of T.
>
> ...
>
> - Otherwise, if M is private, the access is permitted if it occurs within the type in which M is declared.
> - Otherwise, the type or member is inaccessible, and a compile-time error occurs.

So even though it seems *counter-intuitive* to be able to access a *private member* within a *method* (when you only have access to a *reference*), it's still *encapsulated* per se (though you may argue against the definition), and accessible

Comment: ah I see, please bold this one: you can access private fields within the type that defined it.